# React 17 iOS events acting strange

Tags: ios, reactjs

I encountered a weird issue when testing our web application using iOS 15.2.1 (iPad Pro 3rd gen.) or using the Apple iPad Air/Pro Simulator. The same issue is reproducible on Chrome and Safari browsers.

This happen when clicking on two different buttons at medium pace (~500ms). The first click on the first button event fires the proper event handler. Then, when rapidly clicking on the second button, the same event as the first click is fired... This only happens with React 17.0.X. React 16 works as expected.

Here’s the very basic code sample reproducing the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-17-events-issue-safari-mobile-pfztei?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark